# WPF - Adding a Tooltip to a GridViewColumn with DisplayMemberBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` inside a `GridViewColumn` that requires a `DisplayMemberBinding`. The `TextBlock` is completely unaccounted for as `DisplayMemberBinding` takes precedence over `CellTemplate`. However, the `Textblock` has a `ToolTip` that I'd like to be displayed that's specific to the column itself. I was able to move most Style settings outside the `CellTemplate` as they are generic for all columns, but the `ToolTip` cannot be taken outside as it requires a binding and is unique to each column.

Here is one of the columns. Everything within the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` tags is removable due to the `DisplayMemberBinding` taking precedence.

```
            <GridViewColumn Header="Templates"
                            Width="200" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type request:ModelDocument}">
                  <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

The way I've done other Style properties is as follows. This was done before the `GridView` (the `GridView` is a child of the `ListView`):

```
        <ListView.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segue UI Light" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
          </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

How can I add a unique `ToolTip` to each column without removing the `DisplayMemberBinding`?

Comment: Why do you need ``DisplayMemberBinding`` then?

Comment: @CorentinPane It's used in a sorting function as the value to sort by. Trying to remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` would make it very complicated and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Are you intent on using `ListView`? You can just use `DataGrid` if you need some advanced logic, it allows to specify cell styles for example.

Comment: @icebat I suppose so. It's a custom `ListView` and changing it would require time, but if there's no alternative then I can try. With a `DataGrid` can you have a `ToolTip` with `DisplayMemberBinding` then?

Comment: @monadoboi, if your problem was that sorting relied heavily on `DisplayMemberBinding` then it's a XY problem, it all should be more easy to control with DataGrid. But yes, you can.

Comment: @icebat I think you're right. I will try to not use `DisplayMemberBinding` instead and find another way of passing the parameter to my sorting function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already suggested in the comments by @icebat, a `DataGrid` is more suited for such scenarios, for the sake of clarification here a simple demo implementation:

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TbStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segue UI Light" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
        </Style>

    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Templates" SortMemberPath="Name"
                         Width="200"  >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TbStyle}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are more appropriate solutions like using a `DataGrid` instead of a `ListView`, I'd like to show an answer that lets you do *exactly what you want* with a `ListView`, `DisplayMemberBinding` and a `ToolTip` on your `TextBlocks`.

In the end I have the following XAML:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter x:Key="GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter"></local:GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segue UI Light" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />

            <!--THIS IS THE NEW PART-->

            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="Name, Value">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewRowPresenter}"/>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <!--END OF THE NEW PART-->

        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Templates" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Templates" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I added a simple view model class and another `GridViewColumn` for testing purposes:

```cs
public class MyViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Hello.";
    public string Value { get; set; } = "world.";
}
```

This XAML will set the `Name` property of the `DataContext` as `ToolTip` for all `TextBlocks` in the first column, and the `Value` property of the `DataContext` as `ToolTip` for all `TextBlocks` in the second column. You can handle additional columns by adding to the `ConverterParameter="Name, Value"` ordered list of properties.

The key is in the definition of `GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter` (which is one of the least straightforward and most hacky `IMultiValueConverter` I might have ever written):

```cs
public class GridRowPresenterToDataContextPropertiesConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public static T FindVisualSelfOrChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject {
        if (parent == null) return null;
        if (parent is T) return parent as T;
        IEnumerable<DependencyObject> children = Enumerable.Range(0, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)).Select(i => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i));
        foreach (var child in children) {
            T result = FindVisualSelfOrChildren<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result as T;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var presenter = (GridViewRowPresenter)values[0];
        var targetElement = values[1] as FrameworkElement;
        var sourceProperties = ((string)parameter).Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(presenter); i++) {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(presenter, i);
            if (FindVisualSelfOrChildren<TextBlock>(child) == targetElement) {
                var dataContext = targetElement.DataContext;
                return dataContext.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProperties[i].Trim()).GetValue(dataContext);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This converter takes the target element (here, it's gonna be each `TextBlock`), figures out in which column of the `GridView` is lives and extracts the property at the correct index from the `ConverterParameter`.

This answer is more written for fun than for use in production code though, and it will need some smarter code to handle re-ordering of columns which is absolutely not supported now.